# Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible xpath "/html"

Tags: rspec, devise, capybara

I'm writing my first rspec test ever for a 2017 project that uses  capybara, rspec, devise, bootstrap and rails

```
scenario "invalid with unregistered account" do
    
    within('#myNavbar') do
      click_link('LOG IN')
    end  

    fill_in "Email", with: Faker::Internet.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"

    expect(page).to have_content("Email or password fail.")
    expect(page).to have_current_path new_fan_session_path
    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Sign in')
  end
```

This works, but only if I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the layouts/application file. Otherwise, `expect(page).to have_content("Email or password fail.")` gives me error

```
Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible xpath "/html"
```

... I can get around it with `expect(page).to have_css '.alert'` which is the bootstrap alert using save_and_open_page etc to inspect the class.

Otherwise, I have thoroughly inspected the entirety of the path, including all renders etc, for rogue or double    or code outside of these tags etc, and found none.

Any other reason why this error would be occuring?

Comment: have you taken a look into comments added on [this](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/881) issue from capybara -

Comment: yes, from that page I ascertained that it could be any little typo anywhere in the project, including any of the deep capybara, devise or bootstrap files. literally impossible to find